# Нужно сделать перебор словаря по приблизительным значениям

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь, ключи например 0.2311 и 0.2317 нужно сделать так что б при обращении к словарю по ключу 0.2316 выводилось значение по ключу 0.2317, так как оно ближе всего, или наоборот если по ключу 0.2312 выводилось значение по ключу 0.2311

```
k_1_33 = {
1.00:0.00000,
1.01:0.00247,
1.02:0.00490,
1.03:0.00731,
1.04:0.00968,
1.05:0.01203,
1.06:0.01435,
1.07:0.01665,
1.08:0.01891,
1.09:0.02116,
1.10:0.02337,
1.11:0.02556,
1.12:0.02773,
1.13:0.02987,
1.14:0.03199,
1.15:0.03408,
1.16:0.03616,
1.17:0.03821,
1.18:0.04024,
1.19:0.04224,}
reversed_dict = {v: k for k, v in k_1_33.items()}
one_one_etvd = L_tvd/(C_p_gv*T_j_7_8*kpd_tvd)
okr_one_one_etvd = round(one_one_etvd, 4)
pi_tvd = reversed_dict[okr_one_one_etvd]
# okr_one_one_etvd = 0.2133  но если оно будет 0.2134 то такого ключа уже нет
print(pi_tvd)
```

Comment: Сразу скажу что это кусок кода, все переменные объявлены и это не весь словарь, он продолжается

Comment: А вам нужно узнать ключ, или просто значения? Я могу отбросить ключи словаря?

Comment: Вам понадобится не словарь, а другая структура данных - например, сбалансированное дерево поиска, или дерево отрезков. Если набор ключей постоянный - то просто бинарный поиск по сортированному массиву.

Comment: нужно по ключу узнать значение, что за сбалансированное дерево поиска?

Comment: Красно-чёрное, AVL дерево. Набор ключей меняться будет?

Comment: Набор ключей меняться не  будет

Answer (score 1):

Складываете пары ключ-значение в список

Сортируете его (если изначально не отсортировано)

Находите бинарным поиском из `bisect` индекс места `k`, куда можно вставить искомое значение (это даст логарифмическое время поиска, очень быстро)

Проверяете расстояния от искомого значения до ключей `k`-го и `(k-1)`-го, смотрите, какой ближе

Используете второй элемент соответствующей пары.

Answer (score 0):

Как я заметил словарь у вас отсортирован, так что вот простое решение:

Ищем номер элемента, у которого значение больше нашего, и потом смотрим, какое значение ближе

```py
# С list легче работать
k_1_33_list = list(k_1_33.items())

def getKey(find_value):
  for i, key_val in enumerate(k_1_33_list):
    key = key_val[0]
    val = key_val[1]
    if find_value < val:
      prev = k_1_33_list[i-1]

      dist_for_val = val - find_value
      dist_for_next = find_value - prev[1]

      return key if dist_for_val < dist_for_next else prev[0]
```

Если же вам не нужен ключ, а только значение, то всё становится проще:

```py
k_1_33_values = list(k_1_33.values())

def getValue(find_value):
  for i, val in enumerate(k_1_33_values):
    if find_value < val:
      prev = k_1_33_values[i-1]

      dist_for_val = val - find_value
      dist_for_next = find_value - prev

      return val if dist_for_val < dist_for_next else prev
```

Comment: @MBo В задаче мы и не используем ключи

Comment: `one_one_etnd = L_tnd/(C_p_gn*kpd_tnd*T_t_vd)
okr_one_one_etnd = round(one_one_etnd, 4)if okr_one_one_etnd not in reversed_dict_k_1_33.keys():
    for i in range(0,3000):
        okr_one_one_etnd += i*0.0001
        if okr_one_one_etnd in reversed_dict_k_1_33.keys():
            `pi_tnd = reversed_dict_k_1_33[okr_one_one_etnd]'

Comment: Если как нибудь так поработать?

Comment: @Pawel3893 У меня была глупейшая ошибка, исправил код и проверил, теперь всё работает

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/FoOdhQbpuV